# React Native Set Homepage Screen / Main Activity

Tags: react-native

I'm new in react-native. I use `Atom` and `Nuclide` as IDE for my react-native development.

Well, I use `expo init` to build my project. I used project example with 3 navigation bottom bar.

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  LinksStack,
  SettingsStack
});
```

My HomeStack variable

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
});

HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
          : 'md-information-circle'
      }
    />
  ),
};
```

I used `react-navigation` to navigate between screen. Its looks fine. However, I need user going to my login screen before HomeStack loaded up. Let say it LoginScreen. So the screen flow like bellow

```
Splash Screen -> LoginScreen -> HomeScreen (with Bottom Navigation)
```

How to set main screen on react-native? I have been looking several S/O question and post on Medium but didn't catch up anything I looking for.

I have modified MainTabNavigator.js as bellow

```
import LoginScreen from '../screens/LoginScreen';

const LoginStack = createStackNavigator({
  Index: LoginScreen,
});

LoginStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Index',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
          : 'md-information-circle'
      }
    />
  ),
};
```

I've been looking for a whole project to set up default main screen and not found any code section to set up default main screen.
Thanks Guys

Answer (score 0):

[React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html) provides a way for your app to transition between screens.
As per your require `Splash Screen -> LoginScreen -> HomeScreen (with Bottom Navigation)` nested navigation stack will be used with `StackNavigator` & `TabNavigator`.

for Home screen need to create StackNavigator:

```
const stackNavigationHome = createStackNavigator({ Home , HomeDetail});
```

For settings screen StackNavigator like as below:

```
const stackNavigationSetting = createStackNavigator({ Settings},{headerMode: 'none'});
```

Both `Home` & `Settings` screen will be in a `TabNavigator`:

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  home: stackNavigationHome,
  settings: stackNavigationSetting,
});
```

At initial point of stack you need a stack navigation with login and tab as below:

```
const stackNavigationLogin = createStackNavigator({ Login, TabNavigator},{headerMode: 'none'});
```

Navigation structure completed here, now need to create App container :

```
export default createAppContainer(stackNavigationLogin);
```

You can find complete [source on Github](https://github.com/rockyy/React-Native-NestedNavigation)