# I couldn't use react-navigation tab bar. How to use this?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Now I am trying to create React Native app on Expo and use React-Navigation Tab Bar but I could't.

Actually I don't get any error but this code below doesn't work.

No warning as well.

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-   
        navigation';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import Home from './src/Screens/Home';
import Help from './src/Screens/Help';

const App = createBottomTabNavigator(
 {
  Home: {
  screen: Home,
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => {
      <Icon name="home" style={{ width: 25, height: 25, tintColor:       
       tintColor}}/>
    },
    title: 'Home',
  },
},
Help: { screen: Help },
},
{
 swipeEnabled: false, //Android用
 tabBarOptions: {
   activeTintColor: '#DE628D',
   inactiveTintColor: '#707070',
 },
},
);
```

export default createAppContainer(App);

Comment: @ryonz-  You can find on link with demo code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54229716/1042817

Comment: For more info about `react-navigation`. Check this repo https://github.com/adityasonel/TheReactApp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I have solved this issue.

```
const App = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
 Favorite: {
   screen: FavoriteShops,
   navigationOptions: {
     tabBarLabel: 'お気に入り',
     tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Icon name="heart" size={25} color={tintColor} />
    ),
   },
  },
  Home: {
   screen: Home,
   navigationOptions: {
    tabBarLabel: 'ホーム',
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Icon name="home" size={30} color={tintColor} />
    ),
   },
  },
   Help: {
    screen: Help,
    navigationOptions: {
     tabBarLabel: 'その他',
     tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Icon name="bars" size={25} color={tintColor} />
     ),
    },
  },
 },
 {
  swipeEnabled: false, //Android用
   tabBarOptions: {
    showIcon: true,
    showLabel: true,
    activeTintColor: '#DE628D',
    inactiveTintColor: '#707070',
    style: {
     width: '100%',
     height: 70,
   },
    tabStyle: {
     paddingTop: 20,
   },
  },
 },
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

the tab works fine, but if you meant, there's no icon, try this instead

```
navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, activeTintColor }) => (
          <Icon name="home" size={24} color={tintColor} />)
      },
```

Comment: kamu nak join x group fb programmar emma?

Comment: May I know, what do you mean by it didnt work, besides the icon part? I tried to recreate your tabBar, [https://snack.expo.io/@spacechimp/bottomtabnavigator], see if you can get the tab

Comment: boleh saja @Fiido93 , tapi saya masih baru

Comment: kamu dah power dalam react dikira awesome tau.! i satu benda x study pasal react ni. adududu

Answer (score 0):

Please try to implement this way. This is copy of my tabNavigator. Hope this will be helpful for you.

```
const TabRouter = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    HomeAfterLoginScreen: { screen: A },
    ShowListAlertScreen: { screen: B },
    ShowListProfessionScreen: { screen: C },
    MyAccountScreen: { screen: F }
  },
  {
    tabBarPosition: "bottom",
    tabBarOptions: {
      style: { backgroundColor: "#50bcb8" },
      showIcon: true,
      showLabel: true,
      gesturesEnabled: true,
      indicatorStyle: { borderBottomWidth: 3, borderBottomColor: Style.color },
      inactiveTintColor: "#fff",
      activeTintColor: "#fff",
      tabStyle: { justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice but didn't work.
Fortunately I don't have any error but  doesn't work ...