# StackNavigation props not working as expected

Tags: react-native, expo

I've configured the navigation as best I can, however there are no errors when the app runs. The buttons change shade to show they've been pressed but sadly they don't navigate.

I've tried different versions of Expo, React and StackNavigation too.

Here's a copy of the MainNavigator:

```
import ArtGallery from "./ArtGallery";
import HighNet from "./HighNet";
import Economist from "./Economist";
import Main from "./Main";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";

const screens = {
  ArtGallery: {
    screen: ArtGallery
  },
  HighNet: {
    screen: HighNet
  },
  Economist: {
    screen: Economist
  },
  Main: {
    screen: Main
  }
}

const config = {
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Economist'
}

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(screens, config);
export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

And here's a copy of the Main.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Center } from "@builderx/utils";
import Button2 from "../symbols/button2";
import Button21 from "../symbols/button21";
import Button22 from "../symbols/button22";
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";
import { MainNavigation } from "../screens/MainNavigator";

export default class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.root}>
        <Center horizontal>
          <Text style={styles.title}>TV Network</Text>
        </Center>
        <Center horizontal>
          <Button2 
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Winkball")}
          style={styles.winkTv}
          buttonContent="WinkBall TV" />
        </Center>
        <Center horizontal>
          <Button21
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("HighNet")}
            style={styles.highNet}
            buttonContent="High Net Worth Channel"
          />
        </Center>
        <Center horizontal>
          <Button22
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Economist")}
            style={styles.artGalleryTv}
            buttonContent="Economist TV"
          />
        </Center>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    flex: 1
  },
  title: {
    height: "6.19%",
    width: "64.53%",
    top: 68,
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    fontSize: 48,
    color: "rgba(109,104,104,1)"
  },
  winkTv: {
    top: 309,
    position: "absolute",
    height: "5.665024630541872%",
    width: "33.06666666666666%"
  },
  highNet: {
    top: 384,
    position: "absolute",
    height: "5.665024630541872%",
    width: "57.333333333333336%"
  },
  artGalleryTv: {
    top: 460,
    position: "absolute",
    width: "42.13%",
    height: "4.06%"
  }
});
```

Comment: Does navigating to `Economist` works upon pressing `Button22`?

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately. The button changes shade to alert it's been pressed though

Comment: @ThomasCarr- this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/54229716/1042817

Comment: Are the buttons’ `onPress` working? I.e. if you swapped the navigation call for a `console.log` does that work? Have you tried using react-native’s button component? Your initial route name is `Economist` How are you navigating to `Main`?

Comment: Hi again Andrew, the onPress buttons aren't working. And changing the initialRouteName was just for debugging purposes. Sorry I didn't make that clear. And no, the button doesn't work with a console.log call either sadly.