# How to set up app container in React-Navigation-3?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to send data as `initialProps` from Native android to React-Native, but the problem is with `react-navigation` in which I am using `StackNavigator`

This is the solution ([got help from here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/634))
which will work in previous versions of `react-navigation` used to send `initialProps` from native to first scene of react-native:

```
export default class AwesomeProject extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        console.warn(this.props.movie_id);
    }

    render() {
              return <RootStack screenProps={this.props.movie_id} />;
        }
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    { 
        home:  {screen: Details},
        genre: {screen: Genre},
    },
    { 
        initialRouteName: 'home',
    }
);
```

**But** from `react-navigation-3` onwards you must set up app container directly.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this using `createAppContainer()` ?

Comment: Check out this with demo example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54229716/1042817

Comment: Thanks but its working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a sample, from one of my own projects:

```
import {
  createSwitchNavigator,
  createAppContainer
} from 'react-navigation';

const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    ScreenOne,
    ScreenTwo,
    ScreenThree
  }
);
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(SwitchNavigator);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<AppContainer />);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @David Gevorgyan I was successfully able to send `initialProps` from native android to react-native's first scene of `StackNavigator` like this:

```
export default class AwesomeProject extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
    return <RootStack screenProps={this.props.movie_id} />;
  }
}

const RootStack = createAppContainer(StackNavigator)

const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    { 
        home:  {screen: Details},
        genre: {screen: Genre},
    },
    { 
        initialRouteName: 'home',
    }
);
```